# ReactJS unable to setState for products from post API- this.props is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to call a post API to fetch all the products from Node server.

Im able to get the products in the console from response.data, but not able to display in React using setState maybe.

**in Home.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Products from "../Products/Products";

class Home extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        products: [],
        cart: [],
        totalItems: 0,
        totalAmount: 0, 
        term: '',
        category: '',
        cartBounce: false,
        quantity : 1,
        quickViewProduct: {},
        modalActive: false
    };
//UPDATED
this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this)
}

getProducts(){
    //For Localhost use the below url
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/products/getAllProducts?format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
                    
    axios.post(url)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);  //Here i get all the products in the console
            this.setState({        //Error shown here!
                products : response.data  
            })
        })
    }

componentWillMount(){
    this.getProducts();
}

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.category)   //empty here
        return(
             <Products
                productsList={this.state.products}
                searchTerm={this.state.term}
                addToCart={this.handleAddToCart}
                productQuantity={this.state.quantity}
                updateQuantity={this.updateQuantity}
                openModal={this.openModal}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

**Products.js**

```
class Products extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
}
    render(){
    let productsData;
    let term = this.props.searchTerm;
    let x;
    
    function searchingFor(term){
        return function(x){
            return x.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || !term;
        }
    }
    //console.log(this.state.products);
    productsData = this.props.productsList.filter(searchingFor(term)).map(product =>{
        return(
                    /*Edited for debugging only name*/
                    <Product  name={product.product_name} />
            )
        }
    );
    console.log(productsData);
    // Empty and Loading States
    let view;
    if(productsData.length <= 0 && !term){
        view = <LoadingProducts />
    } else if(productsData.length <= 0 && term){
        view = <NoResults />
    } else{
        view = <CSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="fadeIn"
            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={300} 
            component="div"
            className="products">
                {productsData}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
    }
    return(
        <div className="products-wrapper">
            {view}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

**Error trace:**

**TypeError: this.props.productsList.filter is not a function**

> Products.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.productsList.filter is not a function
> at Products.render (Products.js:21)
>
> at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:7873)
>
> at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:7850)
>
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8225)
>
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
>
> at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10288)
>
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:542)
>
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:581)
>
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:438)
>
> at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:10366)
>
> at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:11014)
>
> at Home../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:237)
> at Home.js:62 at anonymous

Console.data:

[image]

Comment: Before render your `<Product>` test if your `this.state.products` have a `length > 0` if not you can render a loading. The error is triggered before your server response.

Comment: axios does that by default

Comment: Looks like `response.data` is not an array ..

Comment: What is the consoled this.state.products in render. Please show what is the console data

Comment: The products state is empty in the beginning which is causing this issue. As you are fetching the data after the component is getting mounted. Not sure where are you calling the getProducts method though.

Comment: response.data is an array and it seems this.state.products is empty..y so and also componentWillMount is calling getProducts()

Comment: Please add the code for Products component as the error is being shown there

Comment: Have updated the Products component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `getProducts` in `componentWillMount/componentDidMount` lifecycle method of the component. And do not forget to bind `this` to the function in the constructor `this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this)`.

Check for empty products list in the component before accessing its data as it will be empty in the beginning and later will be loaded by axios and set to state.

In case where you have no products you can handle that by simply checking the state and returning `null` in the render method or rendering a loader if the required state is empty.

To verify this you can place `console.log` in your render method and check if it is empty or has the list of products.

Example:

```
class XYZ extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    };
    this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getProducts();
  }

  getProducts() {
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/products/getAllProducts?format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

    axios.post(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (
          response.data &&
          response.data.success &&
          response.data.products &&
          response.data.products.length > 0
        ) {
          this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, {
            products: response.data.products
          }))
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.products.length <= 0) {
      return null; // or loader
    }
    return ...;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After looking at your code and response from the api, do set the `products` state to be equal to the `response.data.products` array. Right now you are setting `{success: true, products: [...]}` to the `products` state and using filter on that.

Comment: I already had componentWillMount() and when i console.log(this.state.products) in render() as u say its empty, how to set the state

Comment: Can you update the code above so that I can see where you are calling the `getProducts` function?

Comment: I have updated the code for `getProducts`. Do check if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you are missing is this binding:

```
this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this)
```

place this after initializing state in constructor.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
    }
this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(response.data);
```

response.data is a Object not an array. This is why `.filter` throwing error.

Comment: Thanks for the input